# Solution set of 2 linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Cheers, I have to find the solution set $Λ_{1}$ of the equation $x+2y+3z=0$ and $Λ_2 $ of the equation $ 11x + 18y + 21z = 0$ Lastly, I am asked to find a condition under which $Λ_{1} = Λ_{2}$. My tries are:

Let $Λ_{1}(Σ)$ be the solution set for the first equation, so we have  $Λ_{1}(Σ) = \{ (x, y, z) \in R ^3 
 |(x,y,z) = (-2y-3z,y,z)\}$

Also let $Λ_{2}(Σ)$ be the solution set for the second equation, so we have  $Λ_{2}(Σ) = \{ (x, y, z) \in R ^3 
 |(x,y,z) = (-\frac{18y}{11}-\frac{21z}{11},y,z)\}$

Are these solutions sets okay, or do I have to do anything else? Also can anyone help with the last part of $Λ_1 = Λ_2$?Thanks

Comment: $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ are distinct sets, so there are no "conditions" under which $\Lambda_1 = \Lambda_2$. Perhaps you are asking for the points $(x,y,z)$ that are both in $\Lambda_1$ and in $\Lambda_2$, i.e. the intersection $\Lambda_1 \cap \Lambda_2$.

Comment: This was not specified. I wrote it exactly the way it was given to me. But yes, what you are suggesting is probably the correct thing.

Comment: That is bizarre. If that's the case, do you know how to get the solutions to the system
$$
x + 2y + 3z = 0,\\
11x + 18y + 21 z = 0?
$$

Comment: Also, your characterization of the solution sets is correct, but for instance $\Lambda_1$ could be more clearly written in the form
$$
\Lambda_1 = \{(x,y,z)  \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x = -2y - 3z \} \text{ or }
\Lambda_1 = \{(-2y-3z,y,z) \mid y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$

Comment: I would gladly appreciate some help here, as my teacher introduced us to linear algebra by just giving us this assignment, and not saying a bit of theory. He suggested we should try and find the solution ourselves. I will try to solve it on my own of course, but the solutions would really help!

Comment: Perhaps this would help: if we write it in the form
$$
x + 2y = (-3z)\\
11x + 18y = (-21z),
$$
then we simply have a system of equations with two variables. That is, we can solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$. Perhaps you could figure it out from here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion.  I was told to write it also In another way, which I cannot fully understand however, which went something like this: $Λ_1 = \{  (x,y,z) \in R^3 | (x,y,z) = (-2y,y,0) + ( -3z,0,z) \}$

Comment: I agree with Ben Grossman's comment, and I think that your goal should be something that resembles $[f(y),y,g(y)]$.

Comment: @george.zrs That is also fine. That's a way of writing things that will be very useful once you learn about vector spaces, subspaces, and bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=k$, then solve $x+2y=-3k, 11x+18y=-21k$ to get $=3k, y=-3k$,. Hence
for any value of $k$ these two equations have common solution $(3k,-3k,k)$.

Comment: This regards the last part of $Λ_1=Λ_2$ right?

Comment: Yes, of course.